# C# - Total days between two dates and round up

Tags: c#, date, comparison

I'd like to make an option available if 'now' is two days past start date, but the option must still be valid until the end of the day.

So let's say something has been ordered on:

**10-10-2017 15:00**

The option must be visible on

**12-10-2017 23:59**

I used

```
if (ShippedDate.HasValue && (DateTime.Now - ShippedDate.Value).TotalDays <= 2)
```

However once **48** hours pass, (**12-10-2017 15:01**), it has returned false

I've tried comparing the days, but technically, you could always change it, as long as the (day-2) equals start date.

I'm sure there's a way simpler way of doing this, but I just can't get my mind on it.

---

Thanks for the super fast replies everyone. Ended up using [Tim Schmelter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter)

Comment: It seems here that time is a red herring - seemingly you just need to check the Date parts of the two dates and then check the TotalDays <= 2?

Comment: Dude, you can try to AddDays in the ShippedDate, and then compare to DateTime.Now, like this `if (ShippedDate.HasValue && (ShippedDate.Value.AddDays(2).Date <= DateTime.Now.Date))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) properties which truncate the time portion:

```
bool withinTwoDays = (DateTime.Today - ShippedDate?.Date)?.Days <= 2;
```

(I've also used the [null-conditional-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) to avoid the `null`/`HasValue` check)

Comment: I'll be combining RainMan's answer with your nullcheck. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try like this;

```
if (ShippedDate.HasValue && (DateTime.Now.Date - ShippedDate.Value.Date).TotalDays <= 2)
```

Just use `Date` property.

Comment: Let me try this!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! @Tim Schmelter-  Your answer work aswell.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Date` is not needed, use `DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 1):

Change DateTime.Now to DateTime.Today

```
if (ShippedDate.HasValue && (DateTime.Today - ShippedDate.Value).TotalDays <= 2)
```

Comment: Used Today instead of Now

Comment: I changed DateTime.Now to DateTime.Today in your code. You can try see the result, it will give you the right value.

Comment: Edit a character of your answer and I can remove my downvote. -- There you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ShippedDate.HasValue && (DateTime.Now.Date - ShippedDate.Value.Date).TotalDays <= 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ShippedDate.HasValue && 
     (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(ShippedDate.Value.Year, 
     ShippedDate.Value.Month, ShippedDate.Value.Day, 23,59,59)).TotalDays <= 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

At 15:01 on 12-10-2017 is will already past 48 hours, right ?

so, this condition

```
(DateTime.Now - ShippedDate.Value).TotalDays <= 2
```

will be false.